# Narrowing type based on inferred type from a function parameter used as index for yet another type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out why I can't  narrow the type of the  `parentEntityMetas` below

I'm trying to narrow it down based on `parentEntityType`  passed to the function

I thought  I could get the correct *parentEntityMetas* type from the  *SettingsParentEntityTypeMetas* type using  the inferred (from the param) *parentEntityType* passed as an index to the type

I would expect that the condition I set on the *parentEntityType* would narrow the type but it does not apparently

any help, hints appreciated :slight_smile:

```js
export type SettingsParentEntityType =
  | 'Workspace'
  | 'Artist';

export type SettingsParentEntityTypeMetas = {
  Workspace: {
    workspaceId: string;
  };
  Artist: {
    releaseId: string;
  };
};

type Params<
  T extends SettingsParentEntityType
> = {
  parentEntityType: T;
  parentEntityMetas?: SettingsParentEntityTypeMetas[T];
};

const editor = <
  T extends SettingsParentEntityType
>({
  parentEntityType,
  parentEntityMetas,
}: Params<T>) => {
    const releaseId =  parentEntityType === 'Artist' && parentEntityMetas && parentEntityMetas.releaseId; 
}
```

TS reports an error when trying to access parentEntityMetas.releaseId

the ts playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKwYwJYDsDmAzgAoCGUwuMAoldkgCrKoC8AsAFBxwA+cA5AHVoAa0JhSAY2D9O3PvwCCsbIRj8A3J06hIsBM3SYcBEuUo06jZgFlMpQnBZwA3nLjCoYidIBcr924Ad1FxKWAASQATfzUoPHwtLjgAXyTuZRw1fzdk7goAG2AHSJi4OIT01KS07Q4kFDgyKFIAW0IAHncGOFAYSijHDCwEswoqWhxrFE4APicA5IlxyynEJhR-Birli0n6RDsYBwB+f2GTIma9q3Xbe0IAbQYAXRqkzkkIXDVeqPpoAsusken0BkNjKNrhNbhtgHMABS5bi7GFrOEAGncqNWByODixHBS-mabU6DFmAEonPNkdw4F8fvBCsVCKUFnAcftpqwWM4lCo1Pw4AAyEWc8xovEPUXirm3fGEAB0LJK0Q0cE4KSAA

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified your types in order to achieve desired behavior:

```js
export type SettingsParentEntityTypeMetas = {
  Workspace: {
    type: 'workspace',
    workspaceId: string;
  };
  Artist: {
    type: 'artist'
    releaseId: string;
  };
};

export type SettingsParentEntityType = keyof SettingsParentEntityTypeMetas

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Params = {
  [P in SettingsParentEntityType]: {
    parentEntityType: P;
    parentEntityMetas?: SettingsParentEntityTypeMetas[P];
  }
};

const editor = ({
  parentEntityType,
  parentEntityMetas,
}: Values<Params>) => {
  if (parentEntityMetas) {
    if (parentEntityMetas.type === 'workspace') {
      parentEntityMetas.workspaceId // ok
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFoUwDwBwewE4BcAESCeMIoMoSUgJYB2A5gM4AKAhghMUgKIOEYAqmEAsvteSgF4UAb1AoUAdUQBrcjGoBjCAC4RY8Wk6qA5AHcZcxRG0AadeP0JZ8pQEkAJqvJIEJUgG51AX08hxAQWRCZ1VRPw0MLB1aImdtcxQ6ABsIPggHJxc3X3EfUDywEGh4ZE0sXHwiMipaeiYWdk5BFGkIdDgAMwqCNxq6BmYiRqweJD5wEEjsADVqJIBXCHIAHjYAPma2AG1W9q62AF0JqZQaBGoAW34hMPEtyhQSbqqKM7rB1nQOLAPQhPl%20vUhl8tKcchoAe8GuhRnwAPyqPA9apvAbQ77cXjke4HcFefK%20UAKODEZwoCD2ViIZoACluKEhaOBGLM4UZQM%20sPIrK8qlmCyWyzOl3IawAlIINvTCF0aeyPhguRL6eIZSg5bUmZysQA6E4CA0oPQGGzGZUJcTy6FcnWWaxGBwoAD0TpQcGkCXx4S9XiAA)

```js
export type SettingsParentEntityTypeMetas = {
  Workspace: {
    workspaceId: string;
  };
  Artist: {
    releaseId: string;
  };
};

export type SettingsParentEntityType = keyof SettingsParentEntityTypeMetas

type Params = {
  [P in SettingsParentEntityType]: {
    parentEntityType: P;
    parentEntityMetas?: SettingsParentEntityTypeMetas[P];
  }
};

const editor = <P extends SettingsParentEntityType, M extends Params>(
  parentEntityType:P,
  parentEntityMetas:M[P],
) => {

}
editor('Workspace', )
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is quite close I think but what I wanted to do is to be able to 'pick' a metas object solely based on _parentEntityType_. Is it possible? I did not want to have to add 'extra' info on the metas objects but use their key instead. Let me know if I'm not clear.

Comment: I made an update, see Playground2. Do U mean smth like that?

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll check it out. But I think the playground is broken - or maybe the link

Comment: thanks a lot, tried to tweak you second proposition but could not achieve what I was aiming for

this seems closer to what I had in the first place, but I still get an error when trying to narrow down the metas based on the entity type passed as prop

I'll spend more time on the week end see what I can find out